# Paasing value from onActivityResult to Another method

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

Question:- I want to pass   Fullpath to uploadfile i want to use it in uploadfile
So i have try to catch it with creating the object but it dont work. SO if any solution will really appreciated

```
public void uploadfile(View view){
        edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFile);
/*      Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
*/      if(edittext != null)
        {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, CreateDB.class);
        startActivity(intent1);     
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, "No File Selected", 2000).show();
        }
    }
 // Listen for results.
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        // See which child activity is calling us back.
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PATH){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
                curPathName = data.getStringExtra("GetPath"); 
                curFileName = data.getStringExtra("GetFileName");
                FullPath = curPathName+"/"+curFileName;
                edittext.setText(curFileName);

/*              Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, resId, duration);*/
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: uploadfile is your custom method ?

Comment: yes its my custom method

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

**move EditText intialization in onCreate()**

```
edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFile); 

public void uploadfile(String fullPath) {
    // write your upload file code here
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   if (requestCode == REQUEST_PATH){
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         if(data.getStringExtra("GetPath")!=null && data.getStringExtra("GetFileName")!=null){
            edittext.setText(data.getStringExtra("GetFileName"));
            uploadfile(data.getStringExtra("GetPath")+"/"+data.getStringExtra("GetFileName"));
          }else{
            Toast.makeText(NewMessage.this, "No File Selected", 2000).show();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But I want to show just a file name in my textfield

Comment: So you have just show path on edittext not move another activity ?

Comment: Look this what I exactly need
TextField = FIlename (and nothing else)
And want FullPath variable value to uploadfile

Comment: It will give full path i guess mnt/sdcard/xyz/abc.csv like this and i want to show abc.csv as my text and want to pass "mnt/sdcard/xyz/abc.csv" to upload file

Comment: check again and let me know is it okay ?

Comment: How about making FullPath a global variable

Comment: i think it not required.

Comment: Actually it did work i make the global FUllPath and it worked

Comment: have you required used fullpath any where instead uploadfile ?

Comment: No i dont actually i want to upload a CSV file and store that data in sqlite each and every column of csv to sqlite database of android

Answer (score 0):

change your uploadfile parameter from View to String and remove edittext.

```
public void uploadfile(String fullPath){
    //do something
}
```

Then add this to your onActivityResult method

```
if(!TextUtil.isEmpty(curFileName)){
    tv.setText(curFileName); // show curFileName in textView
    uploadfile(fullPath); // pass fullPath to uploadfile
}else{
    // show Toast, curFileName is empty
}
```

ps: tv is your textView

Comment: But calling an upload file from the onActivityResult will start the code of uploadfile or it will just pass a prameter to it?

Comment: And I have many textfields in that form so if i use TextUtils it will check for every textfield?

Comment: TextUtils(curFileName) only check if curFileName is empty or not. It won't check other variables.

Comment: Ya thats what a thing i dont want to start uploadfile

Comment: when you call uploadfile(curFileName) from onActivityResult, it will pass curFileName to uploadfile as parameter and start the code there.

Comment: so you just want curFileName's value? and not start uploadfile method?

Comment: If it will do show then there will be no use of upload button

Comment: Ya I want current file name to view and want to pass whole path to uploadfile thats exactly what i need something like this
txt = abc.csv
and pass mnt/abc/cde/abc.csv to upload file

Comment: where do you want to show the current file name? textView?

Comment: Ya in textview so edittext.setText(curFileName);
ia fine but i want full path in uploadfile

Comment: Ok i make the variable global and got all solution for the problem